# setting the value to superview,when clicking the subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have dynamically created uiviews,which having many buttons.It is for selecting particular value(uibutton) from  each row(uiview).While clicking the button,I have to get the button image changed(like highlighting).Now I am getting like that,but order is not matching.Buttons are not getting selected in some row.please check the code below

```
for (int j=0; j<[viewTagAry count]; j++)
    {  
        if ([[viewTagAry objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",v]]) 
        {  
            for (int i=0; i<[lastSelectedButtonAry count]; i++) 
            {
                lastSelectedButton=[lastSelectedButtonAry objectAtIndex:i];
                int tag=[[btnTagArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
                UIImage *numImg=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%db.png",tag]];
                [lastSelectedButton setBackgroundImage:numImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
}
}
-(void)highlightButton:(id)sender{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[sender userInfo];
    int t=button.tag+1;

            UIImage *numImg=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%da.png",t]];
            [button setBackgroundImage:numImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];



}
```

Comment: Add one NSLog() to see what's going on before the first line: `NSLog(@"v = %d viewTagAry = %@", v, [viewTagAry description]);` and `show us your bits` ... err, show the output of the NSLog(:-).